# No line-break after align environment

Tags: align, line-breaking, amsmath

Whenever one uses the `align` environment, a line-break is automatically inserted after it:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    1 + 2
\end{align*}
Text
\end{document}
```

The same happens when using two `align` environments after each other (line-break in inserted between them:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    1 + 2
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    3 + 4
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to prevent that from happening, i.e. from having a line-break after an align environment?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I am certainly **not** looking for a simple inline equation. I don't want the results to be in the same line, obviously. I just want to get rid of the extra blank line that separates results.

For instance, with the first code snippet above I get:

[image]

While I would want:

[image]

Similarly, with the second code snippet above I get:

[image]

While I want to have something like:

[image]

Notice, the challenge is doing that **not** using one single `align`.

Comment: Why don't you join the `align`s into a single display?

Comment: What is the point of two separate `align` environments each of which being only one line long?  Try `\begin{align*} 1 + 2
\\    3 + 4 \end{align*}` or `\begin{align*} 1 + 2
& &    3 + 4 \end{align*}`.

Comment: @Werner There are plenty of cases in which separate aligns are useful, like when doing so FOL proofs, even if the line break is wasteful. But never mind, I made the question more general if that helps.

Comment: In your case, an answer would be to use `gather` instead of `align`.

Comment: @Werner There's still the same line-break with `gather`

Comment: So by "no line-break", you want the two `align`s next to one another?

Comment: Are you by chance looking for inline equations like `$1+2$ $3+4$`?

Comment: You could either use `$\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}$`environment or use inline math as ~marmot suggested.

Comment: What I described is certainly not a simple inline equation. I am trying to have, as described, an `align` environment followed by text or another `align` environment - but without any blank lines in-between. The answer posted by GuestUser shows the exact behavior for an `align` followed by text, it just does not work for an `align` followed by another environment (e.g. other `align`).

Comment: @Werner Edited the question and added pictures for clarification.

Comment: @AndraSol: I don't know your setup or that the requirement should adhere to other content that might be around it, but you can set all the spacing around the environment to 0 - [example code](https://pastebin.com/sBRgkRhz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `\centerline` to get what you are hoping:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\newcommand\myalign[1]{\centerline{$\displaystyle#1$}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\myalign{1 + 2}
\myalign{3 + 4}
\noindent text
\end{document}
```

[image]

And while the OP's question doesn't express the need, if you really needed the actual ability to use alignment tabs in the argument, then a TABstack is for you!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\newcommand\myalign[1]{\centerline{\alignShortstack{\strut#1\strut}}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\myalign{1 + 2}
\myalign{y =&3 + 4\\y_1=&4x + 15\\y+y_1 =& 0}
\noindent text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AndraSol Glad to oblige.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\baslineskip`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    1 + 2
\end{align*}
\\[-2\baselineskip]
Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution works for the case of `align` followed by text, but curiously not for `align` followed by another `align`.

Comment: This works for me. I was using `align` followed by `equation`.

Answer (score 2):

`align`, like `\[` is a *display* environment so it always takes the full width of the text block, so it's not really possible to ask for there not to be a linebreak as there is no space after the environment.

You should never start a paragraph with a display environment or have one directly after another, TeX inserts a spurious "blank paragraph" in those cases.

It seems that you want inline math so

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$  1 + 2 $
and
$ 3 + 4 $ and more on the line
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not what I was talking about. What I want to achieve is exactly, as described, to have an `align` followed by either text or by another `align` without the extra line-break.  That is, without a wasteful blank line.

Comment: Edited the question and added pictures for clarification.

Comment: @AndraSol Wow!! I would _never_ have guessed that's what you meant. Given that `Text` is on a new line describing that as having no linebreak after the equation is weird. No real harm done but you may consider editing to change the title of the question. there is no extra linebreak in your example, display math environments are offset by extra vertical space  `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` which you can set to 0pt with `\setlength`

Comment: Many thanks, that last comment was also helpful! And sorry for the confusion.